# How to perform proximity search on a nested array of polygons in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geojson

I have a collection with a nested array of polygons stored in the below given format:

```
_id: ObjectId("...."),
"attributes": {
    "zones": [
      {
        "zoneName": "...",
        "zoneLocs" : [
          {
             "type" : "Polygon",
             "coordinates" : [[...]]
          }
          ....
        ]
      }
      ....
    ]
}
```

I want to perform a geojson search on this collection, where I pass a point and a max-distance value, and pull all the documents which have a polygon in the enclosed area.

I tried to do this by using $elemMatch, $geoWithin and $center. My final query looked like this, but did not fetch any results, even though there were polygons in the enclosing area:

```
  {
      "attributes.zones": {
          "$elemMatch":{
              "zoneLocs": {
                  "$elemMatch" : {
                     "$geoWithin": {
                       "$center" : [
                             [
                               -104.84127910390623,
                                39.820705065855044
                             ], 
                             100000
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
       }
   }
```

I have created a 2dsphere index on the path 'attributes.zones.zoneLocs', but no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No data in the question in order to test against. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nobody can actually tell if you are doing the correct thing or not, nor advise what exactly would be correct unless you provide a **small sample** of data from which they can test obtaining a result themselves. We are not sitting at your desk. All questions need to be self contained with enough information in order to solve them. Otherwise you don't get a correct answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the advice. I will make another post.